# Compile error in work space for IntelliJ editor

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I am new to the IntelliJ editor. I am getting the below compilation error during my workspace set up.

```
Error:(6, 20) java: package javax.inject does not exist a
```

From the error it looks like it is not finding the java libraries. I tried adding the Project SDK and setting the environment variables with `JAVA_HOME`.

My project is a Maven project. I tried re-importing the `pom.xml`. But still the compilation issue is not resolved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310013/package-javax-inject-does-not-exist-error-while-compiling-with-javac-in-comman is for netbeans but will  help.

Comment: i tried adding through the editor (Setting->Module Setting->Adding the SDK) but still it's showing the same error.

Comment: Does the project compiles when using command-line? (If so, try cleaning IntelliJ caches)

Comment: Also try "Rebuild Project". We had a similar frustrating problem with a Gradle project, and "Rebuild Project" fixed it for us.